# Shell script to automate scp queries

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I am trying to create a shell script that will automatically scp using my private key, a port of my choosing and to a commonly used user account (not my own account). I was able to accomplish this for ssh by doing the following.

```
####!/bin/bash

ssh -p (port#) <port #> -i ~/.ssh/.id_dsa  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l admin $@
```

For scp I have the following so far.

```
####!/bin/bash

scp -P (port#) -i ~/.ssh/.id_dsa  $1   admin $@
```

If I try running my command without specifying the username I get the following.

```
user:~$ scputil <file to transfer> host:/tmp
user@10.70.52.18's password:
```

As you can see it is asking for the password of my user when I was hoping it would use admin.

If I specify the user along with my command it works as I would expect

```
user:~$ scputil <file to transfer> admin@10.70.52.18:/tmp/
<file to transfer>                                          22%   78MB  13.1MB/s   00:20 ETA
```

Does anyone know of a way to specify the user for the file transfer within the shell script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

In scp you can use the -o option to pass ssh options, used to log in for the file transfer.

So, if you want to make scp log in as admin, use `User=admin`

so your scp command would become something like

`scp -o User=admin -P port -i public_key $@`

Comment: I reread your question and corrected my answer

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure of the syntax with the -o option.